# dynamically changing height property in javascript does not work after 2 clicks. I want to toggle that continuously as many times as i click

Tags: javascript, html, css

My simple code displaying what i am doing is given below. I am confused that it should work but why its not working as expected.

```js
const caretEl = document.getElementById("caret");
const wrapperEl = document.getElementById("wrapper");
caretEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  caretEl.childNodes[0].classList.toggle("fa-caret-up");
  if (wrapperEl.style.height >= "20vh") {
    // wrapperEl.style.paddingBottom = "1vh";
    wrapperEl.style.height = "8vh";
    console.log("gt 20vh");
    // wrapperEl.style.overflow = "visible";
    // wrapperEl.removeAttribute("overflow");

  } else {
    // wrapperEl.style.paddingBottom = "2vh";
    wrapperEl.style.height = "20vh";
    console.log("lt 20vh");
    // wrapperEl.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
  return wrapperEl.style.height;

})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 8vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.wrapper-header {
  width: 28vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.caret {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-header">
    <p> <b>60%</b> completed. <a href="#">Check the next step</a> </p>
    <span id="caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

on clicking on caret symbol i want the height of "wrapper" div to change dynamically but the code is running only twice it seems. and it does not run any further.

[image: ui image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error lies in the comparison. Since '20vh' and '8vh' are strings, and '8' is chronologically after '2', it results in any string beginning with an '8' being greater than any string beginning with a '2', even if one is just '8', and the other '200'.

I think switching your if statement to:

```
if (parseInt(wrapperEl.style.height) >= 20)
```

Should solve the problem.

I will point out though, there are other solutions for creating an expandable section, even using CSS alone, which are worth looking into. [Here is an example.](https://codepen.io/markcaron/pen/RVvmaz)